# How to remove the white frame around icons on Mi Pad 2 running MIUI 8.5?

Tags: miui

I've noticed my Mi Pad 2 running MIUI 8.5 has this ugly white frame (certainly a poor design choice from Xiaomi's under-qualified design director). I can use a different launcher but when the share menu (for example if I like to share a Youtube video on Facebook) pops up, the icons on the menu still have this ugly white frame (and the icons look very tiny as the result). I tried using the theme manager (link: http://en.miui.com/thread-563883-1-1.html) and it does not show any theme in the store (because there is no theme for Mi Pad 2) and I tried to import themes (.mtz files) via both theme manager or theme editor (link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixapplications.miuithemeeditor), but when I chose the theme, the theme manager will show an alert and tells me it has failed (likely because the theme doesn't work on a tablet or because they are designed for the ARM architecture). Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download this ROM here (http://en.miui.com/thread-358607-1-1.html), it does not have any frame. Use DNX fastboot method to flash.